# Counting the records in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, subquery

In my table i want to find out if the productid exists more then once in the table.
Actually textcode is passing as parameter in where condition.

```
create table productdetails(productid nvarchar(22),textcode varchar(50),textmessage varchar(50))

INSERT INTO  productdetails VALUES('T0001','M0001','ONE')
INSERT INTO  productdetails VALUES('T0001','M0002','TWO')
INSERT INTO  productdetails VALUES('T0009','M0006','THREE')
INSERT INTO productdetails  VALUES('T0002','M0001','FIVE')
```

if i give textcode='M0001' in where condition it gives productid='T0001' AND 'T0002' i want to check whether this productid 'T0001' AND 'T0002' exists more then once in the table.

I used below query.Is it optimized query?or any other method to check this condition.

```
SELECT COUNT(PRODUCTID),PRODUCTID FROM productdetails WHERE productid in(SELECT PRODUCTID FROM productdetails WHERE TEXTCODE='M0001') 
GROUP BY PRODUCTID HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation in the `having` clause to simplify your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), PRODUCTID 
FROM productdetails 
GROUP BY PRODUCTID 
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN TEXTCODE='M0001' THEN 1 END) > 0
AND COUNT(*) > 1
```

This query should give you better performance since you are only accessing the table once.

Please note that for best performance both queries can probably benefit from the same index - an index on TextCode and ProductId (in that order!) should contribute to both queries performance.